# What is the fastest way to check if any files in a directory tree have changed?

Tags: c++, file, search, last-modified

Currently I'm checking against an XOR Checksum of the modified file time (st_mtime from fstat) for every file in the tree. I'm coupling this with the number of files found and a file size checksum (allowing overflows) to be safe but I'm quite paranoid that this can and will lead to false positives in the most extreme pathological cases.

One alternative (safe) option I am considering is keeping a manifest of every file by name and a CRC32 of the file contents. This option however is pretty slow, or slower than I would like at least for many files (lets say thousands).

So the question is, what are some tips or tricks you may have for determining whether any file has changed within a directory tree? I'd like to avoid a byte-by-byte comparison without trading away too much reliability.

Thanks very much for your suggestions.

Comment: While the program is running or since the last run?

Comment: tstenner: If I understand your question correctly since the last run. Given a database of file information, I want to know whether I should update that database after a given duration using just the database information as reference.

Comment: At least, if you want to (probably) spot changes in a collection of datestamps, then take a proper checksum of the data set rather than just an XOR. If you're worried about whether the order that files are returned by `readdir` might change even though the filesystem hasn't, you could sort the files in each directory first (and sort directories during traversal). For instance, suppose I delete two files with the same timestamp, and create two files with another timestamp, perfectly plausible if they're temp files. Your "number of files and XOR of timestamps" metric doesn't spot that.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the "last modified on" property that files have (regardless of platform).

Simply store historical values and check historical values against current values, every so often.

boost::filesystem has a great cross platform API for reading this value.

**EDIT:** Specifically look at:
http://www.pdc.kth.se/training/Talks/C++/boost/libs/filesystem/doc/operations.htm#last_write_time

Comment: Depends how paranoid you want to be.  Most systems will let you set the last modified date, so you can't be sure that it's not been reset.

Comment: Great idea, much quicker than the CRC32. By sorting the file names and appending the mtime together with each sorted name into a coherent file stream I can catch any changes with a (hopefully) quick memcmp!
forsvarir: I'm not too worried about the user modifying this value themselves but good point.

Comment: @Aureis: thats a great way of doing it!

Comment: Link is not working anymore.